# d3.js heatmap not showing data correctly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have the following HTML document with JavaScript embedded where I try to plot a list of JavaScript objects in a d3.js heatmap. But it seems to only show the data of the first row repeatedly on every row. Any help will be greatly appreciated. This is my code and output:

```
<!-- Code from d3-graph-gallery.com -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>

<script>

  // Heatmap data loading
  //document.getElementById("data_display").innerHTML = csvDataString;  //DEBUG

  //var data = {{ heatmap_data|tojson }};

  data = [{group: 'CHEMBL325', variable: 'CHEMBL98', value: 7.2}, {group: 'CHEMBL325', variable: 'CHEMBL99', value: 7.43}, {group: 'CHEMBL325', variable: 'CHEMBL27759', value: 7.31}, {group: 'CHEMBL325', variable: 'CHEMBL2018302', value: 7.19}, {group: 'CHEMBL325', variable: 'CHEMBL483254', value: 7.24}, {group: 'CHEMBL325', variable: 'CHEMBL1213490', value: 7.26}, {group: 'CHEMBL325', variable: 'CHEMBL356769', value: 7.23}, {group: 'CHEMBL325', variable: 'CHEMBL272980', value: 7.21}, {group: 'CHEMBL325', variable: 'CHEMBL430060', value: 7.23}, {group: 'CHEMBL325', variable: 'CHEMBL1173445', value: 7.23}, {group: 'CHEMBL325', variable: 'CHEMBL356066', value: 7.26}, {group: 'CHEMBL325', variable: 'CHEMBL1914702', value: 7.26}, {group: 'CHEMBL1937', variable: 'CHEMBL98', value: 6.94}, {group: 'CHEMBL1937', variable: 'CHEMBL99', value: 7.17}, {group: 'CHEMBL1937', variable: 'CHEMBL27759', value: 7.09}, {group: 'CHEMBL1937', variable: 'CHEMBL2018302', value: 7.06}, {group: 'CHEMBL1937', variable: 'CHEMBL483254', value: 7.14}, {group: 'CHEMBL1937', variable: 'CHEMBL1213490', value: 7.19}, {group: 'CHEMBL1937', variable: 'CHEMBL356769', value: 7.14}, {group: 'CHEMBL1937', variable: 'CHEMBL272980', value: 7.13}, {group: 'CHEMBL1937', variable: 'CHEMBL430060', value: 7.16}, {group: 'CHEMBL1937', variable: 'CHEMBL1173445', value: 7.14}, {group: 'CHEMBL1937', variable: 'CHEMBL356066', value: 7.18}, {group: 'CHEMBL1937', variable: 'CHEMBL1914702', value: 7.17}, {group: 'CHEMBL1829', variable: 'CHEMBL98', value: 7.18}, {group: 'CHEMBL1829', variable: 'CHEMBL99', value: 7.37}, {group: 'CHEMBL1829', variable: 'CHEMBL27759', value: 7.24}, {group: 'CHEMBL1829', variable: 'CHEMBL2018302', value: 7.22}, {group: 'CHEMBL1829', variable: 'CHEMBL483254', value: 7.31}, {group: 'CHEMBL1829', variable: 'CHEMBL1213490', value: 7.35}, {group: 'CHEMBL1829', variable: 'CHEMBL356769', value: 7.31}, {group: 'CHEMBL1829', variable: 'CHEMBL272980', value: 7.24}, {group: 'CHEMBL1829', variable: 'CHEMBL430060', value: 7.29}, {group: 'CHEMBL1829', variable: 'CHEMBL1173445', value: 7.25}, {group: 'CHEMBL1829', variable: 'CHEMBL356066', value: 7.3}, {group: 'CHEMBL1829', variable: 'CHEMBL1914702', value: 7.3}, {group: 'CHEMBL3524', variable: 'CHEMBL98', value: 5.88}, {group: 'CHEMBL3524', variable: 'CHEMBL99', value: 6.39}, {group: 'CHEMBL3524', variable: 'CHEMBL27759', value: 6.3}, {group: 'CHEMBL3524', variable: 'CHEMBL2018302', value: 6.27}, {group: 'CHEMBL3524', variable: 'CHEMBL483254', value: 6.33}, {group: 'CHEMBL3524', variable: 'CHEMBL1213490', value: 6.35}, {group: 'CHEMBL3524', variable: 'CHEMBL356769', value: 6.25}, {group: 'CHEMBL3524', variable: 'CHEMBL272980', value: 6.25}, {group: 'CHEMBL3524', variable: 'CHEMBL430060', value: 6.33}, {group: 'CHEMBL3524', variable: 'CHEMBL1173445', value: 6.32}, {group: 'CHEMBL3524', variable: 'CHEMBL356066', value: 6.46}, {group: 'CHEMBL3524', variable: 'CHEMBL1914702', value: 6.46}, {group: 'CHEMBL2563', variable: 'CHEMBL98', value: 5.74}, {group: 'CHEMBL2563', variable: 'CHEMBL99', value: 6.12}, {group: 'CHEMBL2563', variable: 'CHEMBL27759', value: 6.11}, {group: 'CHEMBL2563', variable: 'CHEMBL2018302', value: 6.09}, {group: 'CHEMBL2563', variable: 'CHEMBL483254', value: 6.24}, {group: 'CHEMBL2563', variable: 'CHEMBL1213490', value: 6.25}, {group: 'CHEMBL2563', variable: 'CHEMBL356769', value: 6.18}, {group: 'CHEMBL2563', variable: 'CHEMBL272980', value: 6.18}, {group: 'CHEMBL2563', variable: 'CHEMBL430060', value: 6.18}, {group: 'CHEMBL2563', variable: 'CHEMBL1173445', value: 6.18}, {group: 'CHEMBL2563', variable: 'CHEMBL356066', value: 6.24}, {group: 'CHEMBL2563', variable: 'CHEMBL1914702', value: 6.23}, {group: 'CHEMBL1865', variable: 'CHEMBL98', value: 7.36}, {group: 'CHEMBL1865', variable: 'CHEMBL99', value: 7.58}, {group: 'CHEMBL1865', variable: 'CHEMBL27759', value: 7.57}, {group: 'CHEMBL1865', variable: 'CHEMBL2018302', value: 7.59}, {group: 'CHEMBL1865', variable: 'CHEMBL483254', value: 7.62}, {group: 'CHEMBL1865', variable: 'CHEMBL1213490', value: 7.56}, {group: 'CHEMBL1865', variable: 'CHEMBL356769', value: 7.54}, {group: 'CHEMBL1865', variable: 'CHEMBL272980', value: 7.54}, {group: 'CHEMBL1865', variable: 'CHEMBL430060', value: 7.51}, {group: 'CHEMBL1865', variable: 'CHEMBL1173445', value: 7.48}, {group: 'CHEMBL1865', variable: 'CHEMBL356066', value: 7.49}, {group: 'CHEMBL1865', variable: 'CHEMBL1914702', value: 7.49}, {group: 'CHEMBL2716', variable: 'CHEMBL98', value: 5.76}, {group: 'CHEMBL2716', variable: 'CHEMBL99', value: 6.19}, {group: 'CHEMBL2716', variable: 'CHEMBL27759', value: 6.19}, {group: 'CHEMBL2716', variable: 'CHEMBL2018302', value: 6.16}, {group: 'CHEMBL2716', variable: 'CHEMBL483254', value: 6.12}, {group: 'CHEMBL2716', variable: 'CHEMBL1213490', value: 6.11}, {group: 'CHEMBL2716', variable: 'CHEMBL356769', value: 5.98}, {group: 'CHEMBL2716', variable: 'CHEMBL272980', value: 5.98}, {group: 'CHEMBL2716', variable: 'CHEMBL430060', value: 5.98}, {group: 'CHEMBL2716', variable: 'CHEMBL1173445', value: 5.98}, {group: 'CHEMBL2716', variable: 'CHEMBL356066', value: 5.98}, {group: 'CHEMBL2716', variable: 'CHEMBL1914702', value: 5.97}, {group: 'CHEMBL3192', variable: 'CHEMBL98', value: 6.19}, {group: 'CHEMBL3192', variable: 'CHEMBL99', value: 6.28}, {group: 'CHEMBL3192', variable: 'CHEMBL27759', value: 6.24}, {group: 'CHEMBL3192', variable: 'CHEMBL2018302', value: 6.22}, {group: 'CHEMBL3192', variable: 'CHEMBL483254', value: 6.27}, {group: 'CHEMBL3192', variable: 'CHEMBL1213490', value: 6.33}, {group: 'CHEMBL3192', variable: 'CHEMBL356769', value: 6.32}, {group: 'CHEMBL3192', variable: 'CHEMBL272980', value: 6.29}, {group: 'CHEMBL3192', variable: 'CHEMBL430060', value: 6.3}, {group: 'CHEMBL3192', variable: 'CHEMBL1173445', value: 6.29}, {group: 'CHEMBL3192', variable: 'CHEMBL356066', value: 6.31}, {group: 'CHEMBL3192', variable: 'CHEMBL1914702', value: 6.31}, {group: 'CHEMBL4145', variable: 'CHEMBL98', value: 6.14}, {group: 'CHEMBL4145', variable: 'CHEMBL99', value: 6.42}, {group: 'CHEMBL4145', variable: 'CHEMBL27759', value: 6.42}, {group: 'CHEMBL4145', variable: 'CHEMBL2018302', value: 6.38}, {group: 'CHEMBL4145', variable: 'CHEMBL483254', value: 6.36}, {group: 'CHEMBL4145', variable: 'CHEMBL1213490', value: 6.33}, {group: 'CHEMBL4145', variable: 'CHEMBL356769', value: 6.28}, {group: 'CHEMBL4145', variable: 'CHEMBL272980', value: 6.28}, {group: 'CHEMBL4145', variable: 'CHEMBL430060', value: 6.28}, {group: 'CHEMBL4145', variable: 'CHEMBL1173445', value: 6.25}, {group: 'CHEMBL4145', variable: 'CHEMBL356066', value: 6.23}, {group: 'CHEMBL4145', variable: 'CHEMBL1914702', value: 6.26}, {group: 'CHEMBL5103', variable: 'CHEMBL98', value: 6.71}, {group: 'CHEMBL5103', variable: 'CHEMBL99', value: 7.12}, {group: 'CHEMBL5103', variable: 'CHEMBL27759', value: 7.01}, {group: 'CHEMBL5103', variable: 'CHEMBL2018302', value: 6.98}, {group: 'CHEMBL5103', variable: 'CHEMBL483254', value: 7.04}, {group: 'CHEMBL5103', variable: 'CHEMBL1213490', value: 7.1}, {group: 'CHEMBL5103', variable: 'CHEMBL356769', value: 7.0}, {group: 'CHEMBL5103', variable: 'CHEMBL272980', value: 7.0}, {group: 'CHEMBL5103', variable: 'CHEMBL430060', value: 7.0}, {group: 'CHEMBL5103', variable: 'CHEMBL1173445', value: 6.97}, {group: 'CHEMBL5103', variable: 'CHEMBL356066', value: 6.99}, {group: 'CHEMBL5103', variable: 'CHEMBL1914702', value: 6.98}, {group: 'CHEMBL3310', variable: 'CHEMBL98', value: 6.7}, {group: 'CHEMBL3310', variable: 'CHEMBL99', value: 6.91}, {group: 'CHEMBL3310', variable: 'CHEMBL27759', value: 6.86}, {group: 'CHEMBL3310', variable: 'CHEMBL2018302', value: 6.82}, {group: 'CHEMBL3310', variable: 'CHEMBL483254', value: 6.79}, {group: 'CHEMBL3310', variable: 'CHEMBL1213490', value: 6.85}, {group: 'CHEMBL3310', variable: 'CHEMBL356769', value: 6.74}, {group: 'CHEMBL3310', variable: 'CHEMBL272980', value: 6.72}, {group: 'CHEMBL3310', variable: 'CHEMBL430060', value: 6.72}, {group: 'CHEMBL3310', variable: 'CHEMBL1173445', value: 6.72}, {group: 'CHEMBL3310', variable: 'CHEMBL356066', value: 6.75}, {group: 'CHEMBL3310', variable: 'CHEMBL1914702', value: 6.76}];

  // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
  var margin = {top: 30, right: 100, bottom: 30, left: 100},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  // append the svg object to the body of the page
  var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  // Labels of row and columns
  var myGroups = ["CHEMBL325", "CHEMBL1937", "CHEMBL1829", "CHEMBL3524", "CHEMBL2563", "CHEMBL1865", "CHEMBL2716", "CHEMBL3192", "CHEMBL4145", "CHEMBL5103", "CHEMBL3310"] 
  var myVars = ["CHEMBL98", "CHEMBL99", "CHEMBL27759", "CHEMBL2018302", "CHEMBL483254", "CHEMBL1213490", "CHEMBL356769", "CHEMBL272980", "CHEMBL430060", "CHEMBL1173445", "CHEMBL356066", "CHEMBL1914702"] 

  // Build X scales and axis:
  var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([ 0, width ])
    .domain(myGroups)
    .padding(0.01);
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    .selectAll("text")
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("x", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(60)")
    .style("text-anchor", "start");  

  // Build Y scales and axis:
  var y = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([ height, 0 ])
    .domain(myVars)
    .padding(0.01);
  svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  // Build color scale
  var myColor = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range(["#ffffff", "#c60606"])
    .domain([5,9])

  //Read the data and add squares
  svg.selectAll()
    .data(data, function(d) {return d.group+':'+d.variable;})
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.group) })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.variable) })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth() )
    .attr("height", y.bandwidth() )
    .style("fill", function(d) { return myColor(d.value)} )

</script>
```

There is the output that I am getting.

[image: output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked your code and there is no mistake. The values are so close that you cannot see the difference.

But you can definitely improve this by improving your color scale. Instead of fixing minimum and maximum value. You can find it from data like below:

// Build color scale
  var myColor = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range(["#ffffff", "#c60606"])
    .domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.value}), d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value})])

You will be able to see that their is slight difference in colors. I hope it resolves your issue.

```html
<!-- Code from d3-graph-gallery.com -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>

<script>
  // Heatmap data loading
  //document.getElementById("data_display").innerHTML = csvDataString;  //DEBUG

  //var data = {{ heatmap_data|tojson }};

  data = [{
    group: 'CHEMBL325',
    variable: 'CHEMBL98',
    value: 7.2
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL325',
    variable: 'CHEMBL99',
    value: 7.43
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL325',
    variable: 'CHEMBL27759',
    value: 7.31
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL325',
    variable: 'CHEMBL2018302',
    value: 7.19
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL325',
    variable: 'CHEMBL483254',
    value: 7.24
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL325',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1213490',
    value: 7.26
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL325',
    variable: 'CHEMBL356769',
    value: 7.23
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL325',
    variable: 'CHEMBL272980',
    value: 7.21
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL325',
    variable: 'CHEMBL430060',
    value: 7.23
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL325',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1173445',
    value: 7.23
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL325',
    variable: 'CHEMBL356066',
    value: 7.26
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL325',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1914702',
    value: 7.26
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1937',
    variable: 'CHEMBL98',
    value: 6.94
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1937',
    variable: 'CHEMBL99',
    value: 7.17
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1937',
    variable: 'CHEMBL27759',
    value: 7.09
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1937',
    variable: 'CHEMBL2018302',
    value: 7.06
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1937',
    variable: 'CHEMBL483254',
    value: 7.14
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1937',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1213490',
    value: 7.19
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1937',
    variable: 'CHEMBL356769',
    value: 7.14
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1937',
    variable: 'CHEMBL272980',
    value: 7.13
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1937',
    variable: 'CHEMBL430060',
    value: 7.16
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1937',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1173445',
    value: 7.14
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1937',
    variable: 'CHEMBL356066',
    value: 7.18
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1937',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1914702',
    value: 7.17
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1829',
    variable: 'CHEMBL98',
    value: 7.18
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1829',
    variable: 'CHEMBL99',
    value: 7.37
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1829',
    variable: 'CHEMBL27759',
    value: 7.24
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1829',
    variable: 'CHEMBL2018302',
    value: 7.22
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1829',
    variable: 'CHEMBL483254',
    value: 7.31
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1829',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1213490',
    value: 7.35
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1829',
    variable: 'CHEMBL356769',
    value: 7.31
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1829',
    variable: 'CHEMBL272980',
    value: 7.24
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1829',
    variable: 'CHEMBL430060',
    value: 7.29
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1829',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1173445',
    value: 7.25
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1829',
    variable: 'CHEMBL356066',
    value: 7.3
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1829',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1914702',
    value: 7.3
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3524',
    variable: 'CHEMBL98',
    value: 5.88
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3524',
    variable: 'CHEMBL99',
    value: 6.39
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3524',
    variable: 'CHEMBL27759',
    value: 6.3
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3524',
    variable: 'CHEMBL2018302',
    value: 6.27
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3524',
    variable: 'CHEMBL483254',
    value: 6.33
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3524',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1213490',
    value: 6.35
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3524',
    variable: 'CHEMBL356769',
    value: 6.25
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3524',
    variable: 'CHEMBL272980',
    value: 6.25
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3524',
    variable: 'CHEMBL430060',
    value: 6.33
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3524',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1173445',
    value: 6.32
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3524',
    variable: 'CHEMBL356066',
    value: 6.46
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3524',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1914702',
    value: 6.46
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL2563',
    variable: 'CHEMBL98',
    value: 5.74
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL2563',
    variable: 'CHEMBL99',
    value: 6.12
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL2563',
    variable: 'CHEMBL27759',
    value: 6.11
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL2563',
    variable: 'CHEMBL2018302',
    value: 6.09
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL2563',
    variable: 'CHEMBL483254',
    value: 6.24
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL2563',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1213490',
    value: 6.25
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL2563',
    variable: 'CHEMBL356769',
    value: 6.18
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL2563',
    variable: 'CHEMBL272980',
    value: 6.18
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL2563',
    variable: 'CHEMBL430060',
    value: 6.18
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL2563',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1173445',
    value: 6.18
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL2563',
    variable: 'CHEMBL356066',
    value: 6.24
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL2563',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1914702',
    value: 6.23
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1865',
    variable: 'CHEMBL98',
    value: 7.36
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1865',
    variable: 'CHEMBL99',
    value: 7.58
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1865',
    variable: 'CHEMBL27759',
    value: 7.57
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1865',
    variable: 'CHEMBL2018302',
    value: 7.59
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1865',
    variable: 'CHEMBL483254',
    value: 7.62
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1865',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1213490',
    value: 7.56
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1865',
    variable: 'CHEMBL356769',
    value: 7.54
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1865',
    variable: 'CHEMBL272980',
    value: 7.54
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1865',
    variable: 'CHEMBL430060',
    value: 7.51
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1865',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1173445',
    value: 7.48
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1865',
    variable: 'CHEMBL356066',
    value: 7.49
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL1865',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1914702',
    value: 7.49
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL2716',
    variable: 'CHEMBL98',
    value: 5.76
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL2716',
    variable: 'CHEMBL99',
    value: 6.19
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL2716',
    variable: 'CHEMBL27759',
    value: 6.19
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL2716',
    variable: 'CHEMBL2018302',
    value: 6.16
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL2716',
    variable: 'CHEMBL483254',
    value: 6.12
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL2716',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1213490',
    value: 6.11
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL2716',
    variable: 'CHEMBL356769',
    value: 5.98
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL2716',
    variable: 'CHEMBL272980',
    value: 5.98
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL2716',
    variable: 'CHEMBL430060',
    value: 5.98
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL2716',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1173445',
    value: 5.98
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL2716',
    variable: 'CHEMBL356066',
    value: 5.98
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL2716',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1914702',
    value: 5.97
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3192',
    variable: 'CHEMBL98',
    value: 6.19
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3192',
    variable: 'CHEMBL99',
    value: 6.28
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3192',
    variable: 'CHEMBL27759',
    value: 6.24
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3192',
    variable: 'CHEMBL2018302',
    value: 6.22
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3192',
    variable: 'CHEMBL483254',
    value: 6.27
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3192',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1213490',
    value: 6.33
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3192',
    variable: 'CHEMBL356769',
    value: 6.32
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3192',
    variable: 'CHEMBL272980',
    value: 6.29
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3192',
    variable: 'CHEMBL430060',
    value: 6.3
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3192',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1173445',
    value: 6.29
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3192',
    variable: 'CHEMBL356066',
    value: 6.31
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3192',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1914702',
    value: 6.31
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL4145',
    variable: 'CHEMBL98',
    value: 6.14
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL4145',
    variable: 'CHEMBL99',
    value: 6.42
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL4145',
    variable: 'CHEMBL27759',
    value: 6.42
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL4145',
    variable: 'CHEMBL2018302',
    value: 6.38
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL4145',
    variable: 'CHEMBL483254',
    value: 6.36
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL4145',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1213490',
    value: 6.33
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL4145',
    variable: 'CHEMBL356769',
    value: 6.28
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL4145',
    variable: 'CHEMBL272980',
    value: 6.28
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL4145',
    variable: 'CHEMBL430060',
    value: 6.28
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL4145',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1173445',
    value: 6.25
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL4145',
    variable: 'CHEMBL356066',
    value: 6.23
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL4145',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1914702',
    value: 6.26
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL5103',
    variable: 'CHEMBL98',
    value: 6.71
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL5103',
    variable: 'CHEMBL99',
    value: 7.12
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL5103',
    variable: 'CHEMBL27759',
    value: 7.01
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL5103',
    variable: 'CHEMBL2018302',
    value: 6.98
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL5103',
    variable: 'CHEMBL483254',
    value: 7.04
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL5103',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1213490',
    value: 7.1
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL5103',
    variable: 'CHEMBL356769',
    value: 7.0
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL5103',
    variable: 'CHEMBL272980',
    value: 7.0
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL5103',
    variable: 'CHEMBL430060',
    value: 7.0
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL5103',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1173445',
    value: 6.97
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL5103',
    variable: 'CHEMBL356066',
    value: 6.99
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL5103',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1914702',
    value: 6.98
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3310',
    variable: 'CHEMBL98',
    value: 6.7
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3310',
    variable: 'CHEMBL99',
    value: 6.91
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3310',
    variable: 'CHEMBL27759',
    value: 6.86
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3310',
    variable: 'CHEMBL2018302',
    value: 6.82
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3310',
    variable: 'CHEMBL483254',
    value: 6.79
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3310',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1213490',
    value: 6.85
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3310',
    variable: 'CHEMBL356769',
    value: 6.74
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3310',
    variable: 'CHEMBL272980',
    value: 6.72
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3310',
    variable: 'CHEMBL430060',
    value: 6.72
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3310',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1173445',
    value: 6.72
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3310',
    variable: 'CHEMBL356066',
    value: 6.75
  }, {
    group: 'CHEMBL3310',
    variable: 'CHEMBL1914702',
    value: 6.76
  }];

  // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
  var margin = {
      top: 30,
      right: 100,
      bottom: 100,
      left: 100
    },
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  // append the svg object to the body of the page
  var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  // Labels of row and columns
  var myGroups = ["CHEMBL325", "CHEMBL1937", "CHEMBL1829", "CHEMBL3524", "CHEMBL2563", "CHEMBL1865", "CHEMBL2716", "CHEMBL3192", "CHEMBL4145", "CHEMBL5103", "CHEMBL3310"]
  var myVars = ["CHEMBL98", "CHEMBL99", "CHEMBL27759", "CHEMBL2018302", "CHEMBL483254", "CHEMBL1213490", "CHEMBL356769", "CHEMBL272980", "CHEMBL430060", "CHEMBL1173445", "CHEMBL356066", "CHEMBL1914702"]

  // Build X scales and axis:
  var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain(myGroups)
    .padding(0.01);
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    .selectAll("text")
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("x", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(60)")
    .style("text-anchor", "start");

  // Build Y scales and axis:
  var y = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain(myVars)
    .padding(0.01);
  svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  // Build color scale
  var myColor = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range(["#ffffff", "#c60606"])
    .domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.value}), d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value})])

  //Read the data and add squares
  svg.selectAll()
    .data(data, function(d) {
      return d.group + ':' + d.variable;
    })
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.group)
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.variable)
    })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return myColor(d.value)
    })

</script>
```